# LyX cant use "view" button, exporting PDFs works flawlessly

Tags: pdftex, lyx, miktex, viewers

I installed recently LyX with MiKTeX and executed an external program that changed the definitions so that I can export with foreign languages.

While exporting (using "pdflatex") works great, the view option stopped working and I suspect the external program is to be blamed. My computer is x64 system based.

My LyX version info:

> LyX Version 2.3.1-1
>
> (Saturday, September 29, 2018)
>
> Library directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\Resources\
>
> User directory: ~\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.3\
>
> Qt Version (run-time): 5.10.1
>
> Qt Version (compile-time): 5.10.1

The error log reads:

> The external program pplatex finished with an error.
>
> It is recommended you fix the cause of the external program's error
> (check the logs).
>
> 12:08:57.934: Error while exporting format:
>
> PDF (dvipdfm) 12:09:39.663: (buffer-switch
> C:/Users/~/OneDrive/Documents/newfile1.lyx)
>
> 12:09:51.914: (dialog-toggle progress)
>
> 12:10:57.364: Automatic save done.
>
> 12:15:57.397: Automatic save done.
>
> 12:16:47.470: (dialog-show aboutlyx)
>
> 12:20:57.425: Automatic save done.

I also receive a system error

> titled: pplatex.exe - System Error
>
> The code execution cannot be proceed because MSVCR100.dll was not
> found.
>
> reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

The file is not in the latex bin folder but when I copied the file from C:\Windows\System32 it still didn't work.

I tried adding C:\Windows\System32 to the Lyx path or installing Microsoft Visual C++2010 Redistributable Package and still nothing seemed to work.

Maybe an easier way will be to change "view" default from pplatex to pdflatex but I have failed to find how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix is to use the "view as" button and pick each time pdflatex option.
But i'd like to be able to use the short cut ctrl+R